# SQL Joining 2 similar tables

Tags: php, sql, join

I have two tables which are used to store details of different types of events.
The tables are almost identical, with fields such as date, duration etc.  I'm trying to perform a join on the two tables and sort them by the mutual field 'date'.

I know it would be simpler to simply add a 'type' field to a single table and store it all in a single place, unfortunately the nature of the cms I am using does not allow this.

Is there a way to perform this simply?  The following query returns no results.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Events_One a, Events_Two b WHERE a.Date > now() OR b.Date > now() ORDER BY Date ASC LIMIT ".$limit;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) statement. It does exactly what you need.

```
SELECT columns FROM t1
UNION
SELECT columns FROM t2
```

gives you one set, which you can later filter or sort by whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table for each event type, with *identical* fields for each one, I'd say that you should reconsider your design.  That's breaking normalization rules.  It's a poor design because it forces you to add another table every time a new event comes along.  It's better if you can add a new event by adding data, like a new type value, to an existing table.

Comment: He clearly stated, that in his problem this solution is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, it's not my design unfortunately;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two similar  tables You can use  Union or union all

Union:its Like a join Command.When using the union all the selected columns need to be of the same datatype.Only distinct values are selected.

Union All :it almost like union.There is no distinct operation so it will take all the values.

```
select  * FROM Events_One a   WHERE a.Date > now() 
union 
select  * FROM Events_Two b   WHERE b.Date > now()
```